# Retrieving Model with Array Object from a Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model that has an object array as one of its attributes. For example:

```
class Person {
 int id;
 string name;
 int age;
 Work[] workExperiences;
}

class Work {
 int id;
 string address;
 string position;
}
```

Person and Work are tables in the database. How do I create a stored procedure so I can retrieve all the information in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what kind of database server you're using or by what means you're approaching the database (`EntityFramework`, various OR/M, direct `SqlConnection`, ...) I'll make the assumption you're using `MSSQL Server` and `SqlConnection`.

Let's say you have a very simple stored procedure called `GetPersonAndWorkExperience` that takes a `PersonID` as an argument.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE GetPersonAndWorkExperience
@PersonID INT

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        p.PersonID,
        p.Name,
        p.Age,
        w.WorkID,
        w.WorkAddress,
        w.Position
    FROM Person p
    INNER JOIN Work w ON w.WorkID = p.PersonID
    WHERE p.PersonID = @PersonID
END
GO
```

This will return a result set with everything you need.

If you're approaching your database with `SqlConnection`, this is how you'd call the stored procedure and return the data using your model classes as specified in your question. For convenience, I'm converting your array to a `List<Work>`.
I'm also renaming address to `WorkAddress` because `address` is a reserved word in SQL and it's bad practice to name your columns as such.

```
public DataTable GetPersonAndWorkExperience(int personId)
{
    string connectionString = ""; //load connection string here
    DataTable result;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetPersonAndWorkExperience"))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PersonID", personId));
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;

            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
            {
                result = new DataTable();
                result.Load(rdr);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Now you have a `DataTable`. You can now do something along the lines of

```
Person p = new Person
{
    Id = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0].Columns["PersonID"]),
    Name = dt.Rows[0].Columns["Name"]),
    Age = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0].Columns["Age"])
};

p.WorkExperiences = new List<Work>();

List<Work> workExperiences = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                             select new Work
                             {
                                 Id = row.Field<int>("WorkID"),
                                 WorkAddress = row.Field<string>("WorkAddress"),
                                 Position = row.Field<string>("Position")
                             }).ToList();

p.WorkExperiences.AddRange(workExperiences);
```

Please note that this demonstrates the gist of it and might not compile as it was written in a text editor but you get the idea.

Oh, if you really want to keep your array, you could initialize it with the `DataTable`'s row count, of course.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I am using SqlConnection, sorry if I hadn't made that clear. I thought it could retrieve the list of Work objects without looping through the result set. Your solution helped me a ton.